# (Ruby) Handle race condition when multiple processes download the same file

Tags: ruby, race-condition, puma

In my application (Sinatra with Puma - 2 workers 8 threads) several processes need the same file to perform some operations. The file is downloaded from Google Storage if not available locally. The problem arises when one process has started to download a file, but not completed.

- If I check for the file to exist before downloading, I often find that the download, started from another process, has not completed yet and the downstream code of the current process fails.
- The files are small so I also tried to download the same file every time, but this causes a similar issue, because the file already exists.

I have implemented a **very crude hack** by waiting for 1 sec if the file already exists. The assumption being that, if the file exists, it is either downloaded or being downloaded and becaude they are small 1 sec should be more than enough to complete.

```
def download_file(args)

    # Previous code
    
    # Download the file from GCS
    puts "Downloading #{blob_name}..."
    bucket = storage.bucket bucket_name
    file = bucket.file blob_name
    downloaded_file_path = File.join(@weather_data_dir, closest_document[:file_name])

    if File.exists?(downloaded_file_path)
        puts "File already downloaded or downloading"
        sleep(1)
    else
        puts "to #{downloaded_file_path}"
        file.download(downloaded_file_path)
    end

    return closest_document[:file_name]
end
```

The problem with this hack is that there might be hundreds of these processes and the 1 sec pause adds up.

From my research, I believe that this is called a race condition. I have tried to implement a file lock, but then the race conditon happens on the lock file.

How should I approach this? Would something like job queues help?

Comment: Given that the files are small is there a reason to download them locally at all? I am obviously not familiar with what you are doing but it seems like you should be able to just stream the file for processing. If you have to download it then why not download into a `Tempfile` to avoid the collision.

Comment: I need to download it because I pass to an external executable. I thought about downloading it to temp files with different names, but sometimes I have to download it hundreds of times. Maybe I just need to rethink the approach.

Comment: You can pass Tempfiles to external processes, too. Or file handles. Or binary blobs. You're boxing yourself in by trying to do asynchronous operations with a  single, static filename.